# How to I get the list of week days for a specific date in android

Tags: android, date, android-calendar

I'm implementing the material calendar view in android app,the user can select a particular date in the calendar.how do i get the complete list of week days for that particular selected date

for example: if user selects 22 as the date,how do i get the week days in that row from calendar in which 22 is present

Comment: I think you need to customize the calendar as per the requirement.

Comment: i'm using https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview as the library,any help or ideas?

Comment: try caldroid library instead. you can easily customise it.

Comment: any code samples,for my requirements,pls help

Comment: You can choose `android-week-view` also. this might help https://android.libhunt.com/project/caldroid/vs/android-week-view

Comment: thanks,for the help[

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is unclear. If you want to get the week day for that day, you can use
`Calendar.getInstance().set(year, month, day);
int dayOfWeek = Calendar.getInstance().DAY_OF_WEEK;`

Ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: not a day of week,i need to get the list of days from the calender row corresponding to the selected dates...for example:suppose that user selects  22 of october,i need to retreive all the remaining week days of thar row in which 22 falls

Comment: you mean for 22 oct 2016, you wanna get {16, 17, ..., 22} like this?

Comment: sure,exactly thats what i need

Comment: you can add and subtract 7 days using calendar function add() and check accordingly to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public String[] getWeekDaySelected(String selectedDateStr) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        try {
            Date startDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Date endDate = sdf.parse(selectedDateStr);
            weekDaysCount = Functions.getWeeksBetween(startDate, endDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String[] days = new String[7];
        // set the011, 10 - 1, 12);
        String[] arr = selectedDateStr.split("-");
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, (Integer.parseInt(arr[1]) - 1));
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
        Calendar first = (Calendar) cal.clone();
        first.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, first.getFirstDayOfWeek() - first.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        first.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

        // and add six days to the end date
        Calendar last = (Calendar) first.clone();
        last.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 6);

        // print the result
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(df.format(first.getTime()) + " -> " +
                df.format(last.getTime()));

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            days[i] = format.format(first.getTime());
            first.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        return days;

    }
```

Comment: i'll try and let u know

Comment: what does this line mean..?what exactly is Functions in the following line ?weekDaysCount = Functions.getWeeksBetween(startDate, endDate);